# Capitalize the first letter matching a pattern

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a dozens of files that contain the following text:

```
request {
      Request {        
        input("testing")
      }
}
```

I would like to use sed to capitalize the first letter of any text within input. For example, I want testing to be Testing. I tried the following command to capitalize the beginning of all, but how can I only apply it to input ?

```
sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g"
```

Comment: not very sure why `testing` has to be capitalized and why not `request`

Comment: should`input("test test")` convert to `input("Test test")`, or `input("Test Test")`?

Comment: input("testing") should be input("Testing")

Comment: also, different files contain different contents, so for another file, I may want to have input("hello") to be input("Hello"), there wouldn't be more than one word in input

Comment: Better update your question with a proper description and broader set of input / desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
sed 's/input("\(.\)/input("\u\1/'
```

**Test**

```
$ echo -e 'request {
      Request {        
        input("testing")
      }
}' | sed 's/input("\(.\)/input("\u\1/'
# Outputs
# request {
#      Request {        
#        input("Testing")
#      }
#}
```

**What it does?**

- `/input("\(.\)` Matches `input("` followed by the first character( in example `t`. The character matched by `.` is captured in `\1`
- `input("\u\1` Replacement string. `input("` is replaced with itself. `\u\1` converts the character captured in `\1` to uppercase.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is not POSIX-compliant so will only work on some versions of sed (GNU sed, for instance).

Comment: I commented up there, I need to maintain the input as it is and not convert it to testing.

Comment: @TomFenech Tested in `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2` Am not sure of older versions :(

Comment: @AlexCon Sorry that was a typo. Corrected in answer